# python's re: return True if string contains regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression like this:

```
regexp = u'ba[r|z|d]'
```

Function must return True if word contains **bar**, **baz** or **bad**.
In short, I need regexp analog for Python's

```
'any-string' in 'text'
```

How can I realize it? Thanks!

Comment: Just use ``bool(re.search('ba[rzd]', 'sometext'))``.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger why do you need `bool`?

Comment: @igorkf you can use `bool` for typing. e.g. `def f(x: bool) -> bool: ... body etc` cheers!

Answer (score 234, accepted):

```
import re
word = 'fubar'
regexp = re.compile(r'ba[rzd]')
if regexp.search(word):
  print('matched')
```

Comment: I am working on a similar case where I want to search for an exact string (`xyz`) and want to know which is a more efficient way to do this, should I use python's `'xyz' in given_text` or use `re.compile(r'xyz').search(given_text)` ?

Comment: the `[]` brackets contain a character class, so your re also matches: >>> word = 'ba|'; regexp.search(word)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x101030b28> . You can drop all the pipe symbols.

Comment: why do you need the `r` in front of your string? i.e. what is the difference between `re.compile(r'x[\d+]')` vs `re.compile('x[\d+]')`?

Answer (score 166):

The best one by far is

```
bool(re.search('ba[rzd]', 'foobarrrr'))
```

Returns True

Comment: Why is this one better than the other solutions?

Comment: For one thing, it returns a `bool`. OP: "must return `True` if word contains bar, baz or bad." Other answers use the behavior of `if` - auto-converting the expression to its right to a `bool`. e.g. `import re; rgx=re.compile(r'ba[rzd]'); rgx.search('foobar')` => `<re.Match object; span=(2, 5), match='bar'>`, but `if(rgx.search(w)): print('y')` => `y`. [Closest to documentation of auto-convert I could find](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/boolean.html)([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20200319164133/http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/boolean.html))

Comment: why did you prefer `.search` vs `.match`?

Comment: also why did you not use `r` infront of the regex e.g. `re.compile(r'x[\d+]')` vs `re.compile('x[\d+]')`?

Answer (score 21):

`Match` objects are always true, and `None` is returned if there is no match. Just test for trueness.

Code:

```
>>> st = 'bar'
>>> m = re.match(r"ba[r|z|d]",st)
>>> if m:
...     m.group(0)
...
'bar'
```

Output = `bar`

If you want `search` functionality

```
>>> st = "bar"
>>> m = re.search(r"ba[r|z|d]",st)
>>> if m is not None:
...     m.group(0)
...
'bar'
```

and if `regexp` not found than

```
>>> st = "hello"
>>> m = re.search(r"ba[r|z|d]",st)
>>> if m:
...     m.group(0)
... else:
...   print "no match"
...
no match
```

**As @bukzor mentioned if st = `foo bar` than match will not work. So, its more appropriate to use `re.search`.**

Comment: As I understand the question, OP actually wants `search` rather than `match`. (See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching.) Also, I think it would be helpful if you showed actual possible arguments, in the correct order, rather than just `...`.

Comment: if you change `st` to `"foo bar"`, the match method will not work here. You want search.

Comment: @ruakh that link no longer auto scroll to that part of the doc, now the link is https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Comment: @RanRag what is the complexity difference in searching substring with `in` and `regex`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that does what you want:

```py
import re

def is_match(regex, text):
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    return pattern.search(text) is not None
```

The regular expression search method returns an object on success and None if the pattern is not found in the string. With that in mind, we return True as long as the search gives us something back.

Examples:

```py
>>> is_match('ba[rzd]', 'foobar')
True
>>> is_match('ba[zrd]', 'foobaz')
True
>>> is_match('ba[zrd]', 'foobad')
True
>>> is_match('ba[zrd]', 'foobam')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Using search will return a SRE_match object, if it matches your search string.

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(u'ba[r|z|d]', 'bar')
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02027288>
>>> m.group()
'bar'
>>> n = re.search(u'ba[r|z|d]', 'bas')
>>> n.group()
```

If not, it will return None

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    n.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

And just to print it to demonstrate again:

```
>>> print n
None
```